# how to get the value of an element in the url after #?

Tags: php, wordpress

i write 
< ?  php

if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){

echo $_REQUEST['id'];

} ? >

< a href="#id=3" >  click < /a >

But I didn't get the value of id.. How can i get it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it since the string after `#` is interpreted by the browser as anchor name so it'll not being passed to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with php, because the value after hash cannot send to server. You can use js to send it to server like;

```
var hash = window.location.hash;

$.get("get_hash.php?hash=" + hash, function(response) {
    // handle response
});
```

in `get_hash.php`:

```
$hash = $_GET['hash']; //#id=4
$remove_hash = substring($hash, 1, strlen($hash) - 1); //id=4
$id_arr = explode("=", $param_arr[1]); // 0=> id, 1=> 4
echo "id=" . $id_arr[1]; // 4
```

Comment: i write   <?php

$url_param = $_REQUEST['page'];
$param_arr = eplode("#", $url_param); 
$id_arr = explode("=", $param_arr[1]); 
echo "id=" . $id_arr[1];
?>
<a href="#id=3">click</a>  but here were errors, Notice: Undefined index: page in H:\xampp\htdocs\upload\hi.php on line 3

Fatal error: Call to undefined function eplode() in H:\xampp\htdocs\upload\hi.php on line 4

Comment: @Harry, you cannot get hash value on server side, you need to send value after hash by using javascript. I have provided you quick example

Answer (score -1):

Try this for getting the value of last parameter.

```
$url = "localhost/gft/wp-admin/admin.php?page=abc-yu#id=4";

$last = end(explode("=",$url));

echo $last;
```